# MS Access using UPDATE statement keeps entering new data

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using an UPDATE Statement but whenever I click the `Edit` button then `Update`, it's entering a new line but with the same data.

**My code:**

```vb
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'when we click on button Add there are two options
'1. for insert
'2. for update
If Me.txtNumber.Tag & "" = "" Then
    'this is for insert new
    'add data to table
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblcompany (companyname, companyaddress, contactnumber, contactperson, emailaddress, website, plantlocation, projectinfo, consultant) " & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.txtCompanyName & "','" & _
                     Me.txtCompanyAddress & "','" & Me.txtContactNumber & "','" & _
                     Me.txtContactPerson & "','" & Me.txtEmailAddress & "','" & _
                     Me.txtWebsite & "','" & Me.txtPlantLocation & "','" & _
                     Me.txtProjectInfo & "','" & Me.txtConsultant & "')"

Else
    'otherwise (tag of txtNumber store the number of company to be modified)
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblcompany " & _
            " SET companyname='" & Me.txtCompanyName & "''" & _
            ", companyaddress='" & Me.txtCompanyAddress & "''" & _
            ", contactnumber='" & Me.txtContactNumber & "'" & _
            ", contactperson='" & Me.txtContactPerson & "''" & _
            ", emailaddress='" & Me.txtEmailAddress & "'" & _
            ", website='" & Me.txtWebsite & "'" & _
            ", plantlocation='" & Me.txtPlantLocation & "''" & _
            ", projectinfo='" & Me.txtProjectInfo & "''" & _
            ", consultant='" & Me.txtConsultant & "''" & _
            "  WHERE number=" & Me.txtNumber.Tag
End If


 'clear form
 cmdClear_Click

'refresh data in list on form
frmCompanySub.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Right above your Update statement put in this: `MsgBox "Update Statement Reached"` and see if it pops up when you expect the `Update` statement to run.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but still nothing happens. It keeps on entering new data whenever i click the update button.

Comment: So what would you think is happening if the Msgbox never pops up?

Comment: I dont have enough knowledge on vba codes thats why im here asking for a help. I just copied and edit those codes on some tutorial videos that i see on the internet but still cant execute it properly. theres something wrong with my codes but i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the Tag property empty by default? if you're saving a new record you will have to set a tag property equal to the number. So that when you come to update a record the `Where number = & me.txt.number.tag` is true. Otherwise all record tags of "" will equal "".

Also, tab in on your `currentDb.execute` line (after `then`).